# Ordering of kotlin co-routines inside the same launch block

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am learning Kotlin co-routins and I have a doubt. This is a sample program I made, over here:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit {
  runBlocking {
    println("A")
    launch {Dispatchers.Main
      suspendFunction()
      suspendFunction2()
    }
    println("I am here")
  }
}

suspend fun suspendFunction() {
  println("Running on thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
  delay(10000) // Simulating a suspend operation
  println("B")
}

suspend fun suspendFunction2() {
  println("Running on thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
  delay(1000) // Simulating a suspend operation
  println("C")
}
```

The output that is printed is:

```
A
I am here
Running on thread: main
B
Running on thread: main
C
```

But I wonder, why is it that when main thread is waiting for `delay` to complete in `suspendFunction()` why does it not start executing the `suspendFunction2()`?

Comment: You created ONE co-routine.  That co-routine calls two functions in serial order.  Perhaps you wanted two `launch` blocks.  And `Dispatchers.Main` is supposed to be a parameter to `launch`, not a statement with it.

Comment: This is by design. Coroutines are sequential by default and concurrent if needed. This is actually one of their biggest advantage. We write the code as any other sequential code. No need to use some callback hell just to perform 4 operations one after another.